# Check duplicate entry into object array php laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, duplicates

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => User Object
                (
                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 123456
                            [active] => 1
                            [name] => ABC XYZ
                            [first_name] => ABC
                            [last_name] => XYZ
                            [email] => abc@xyz.com
                            [username] => abcxyz
                            [secret_code] => S4#$sdD                           
                        )
                )

            [1] => User Object
                (

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 987654
                            [active] => 1
                            [name] => CBD IHK
                            [first_name] => CBD
                            [last_name] => IHK
                            [email] => abc@xyz.com
                            [username] => seCdils
                            [secret_code] => S4#$sdD
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Identify both object array has same secret_code return boolean if exist true else false tried array_count_values return only string and number please guide thanks

I just want to check if detect secret_code same in array give me true else false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP unique array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422562/php-unique-array-by-value)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Comment: I just want to check if detect secret_code same in array give me true else false

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$dupes = []; // keep track of duplicates
foreach ($users as $user1) { // iterate over all items
    $dupeCount = 0; // because we iterate over the same array, we always find at least the item itself (1 dupe minimum)

    foreach ($users as $user2) { // check the array again
        if ($user1 === $user2) { // if they are exactly the same: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php
            $dupeCount++;
        }
        if ($dupeCount > 1) { // because we always find at least 1, push only when we find more than that
            array_push($dupes, $user1); // add it to the result
        }
    }
}
```

However for you comment

> I just want to check if detect secret_code same in array give me true
>   else false

which should be in your question to begin with.

```
collect($users)->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['secret_code'];
});
```

Comment: What is collect..? says undefined

Comment: collect is a function that creates a collection from an array: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: Bdw I'm using 4.2 this does not work, hope you understand my question if $users[0]['secret_code'] exactly match  with $users[1]['secret_code'] should return true else false

Comment: @Ross you using v4.2 is something you should mention before, this way you do too little effort and the person(s) trying to answer you have to do too much guesswork.